# Python how to delete first line of word file and font.bold not working

Tags: python, aspose.words

I am writing a python program that open a docx file and writing text into it. using "aspose.words"
and I have two problems:

1. I have a problem that when I open a file its starting with the sentence

> "Evaluation Only. Created with Aspose.Words. Copyright 2003-2021 Aspose Pty Ltd."

and I want to delete that line after I creating the file (I can delete it manually so it's deletable)

2. my second problem is when I am using "font.bold = True" on an english text it's working just fine but when I am using it on an text that in other language its doesen't work.
   Someone know how can I solves those two problems (it's the first time I am using "aspose.words")

here is my code:

```
import aspose.words as aw

def main():
    doc = aw.Document()
    builder = aw.DocumentBuilder(doc)
    writeDest(1, builder)
    doc.save("out.docx")

def writeDest(designation, builder):
    font = builder.font
    font.size = 12
    font.bold = True
    font.name = "David"
    paragraphFormat = builder.paragraph_format
    paragraphFormat.alignment = aw.ParagraphAlignment.RIGHT
    label = 'ייעוד: ' + str(designation)
    builder.write(label)
    builder.write("\n")
    font.bold = False
    if designation == 1:
        file = open('destenationTextFiles/1', encoding="utf8")
        for word in file:
            builder.write(word)
        builder.write('\n')
        font.bold = True
        builder.write(':תיקון ')
        builder.write("\n")
        font.bold = False
        file.close()
        file = open("destenationTextFiles/fixed1", encoding="utf8")
        for word in file:
            builder.write(word)
        file.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

1. This message indicates you are using Aspose.Words in evaluation mode. Please see the following article to learn more about [evaluation version limitations](https://docs.aspose.com/words/python-net/licensing/#free-trial) of Aspose.Words.
   To test Aspose.Words for Python without these limitations you can request a temporary 30 days license.
2. To format right-to-left text you should use bidi font properties. For example see the following python code:

```py
import aspose.words as aw

def main():

    doc = aw.Document()
    builder = aw.DocumentBuilder(doc)

    # Define a set of font settings for left-to-right text.
    builder.font.name = "Courier New"
    builder.font.size = 16
    builder.font.italic = False
    builder.font.bold = False
    builder.font.locale_id = 1033

    # Define another set of font settings for right-to-left text.
    builder.font.name_bi = "David"
    builder.font.size_bi = 24
    builder.font.italic_bi = True
    builder.font.bold_bi = True
    builder.font.locale_id_bi = 1037;

    # We can use the Bidi flag to indicate whether the text we are about to add
    # with the document builder is right-to-left. When we add text with this flag set to true,
    # it will be formatted using the right-to-left set of font settings.
    builder.font.bidi = True
    builder.write("ברוך הבא")

    # Set the flag to false, and then add left-to-right text.
    # The document builder will format these using the left-to-right set of font settings.
    builder.font.bidi = False
    builder.write(" Hello world!")

    doc.save("C:\\Temp\\Font.Bidi.docx")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```